# Primitive $n$-th roots of unity and Euclidean domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $w$ is a primitive nth root of unity , is $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ a Euclidean Domain?
I find that up to $n=4$ it is true. Is it true when $n>4$?

Comment: In fact, there are only finitely many values of $n$ for which it holds. You can find information [in this senior thesis](https://reza-akhtar.github.io/research/final/seniorthesis.pdf) by Reza Akhar. There are only 46 values of $n$ for which $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is a UFD; only those could possibly be Euclidean. The introduction to the thesis in the link has some of the history up to 1995.

Comment: Masley and Montgomery, Cyclotomic fields with unique factorization, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (1976) Volume: 0286_0287, page 248-256, https://eudml.org/doc/151787

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the literature that you enclosed. Exactly what I was looking for.